# &char and char pointer is incompatible pointer type?

Tags: c

```
char filename[100];
char *file;
fgets(filename,100,stdin);
file =&filename;
```

give this warning:

```
warning: assignment from incompatible pointer type [enabled by default] 
file =&filename;
```

Isn't &filename and file have the same type as address of character since i use & to get address of the variable?

Comment: The `[ ]` actually mean something...

Answer (score 7):

Your variable `file` has type `char *` but when you apply the address-of operator `&` on your array `filename[100]`,it has type `char (*)[100]`.

obviously,types `char *` and `char (*)[100]` are incompatible.To solve the problem either write:

```
file = filename;
```

or

```
file = &filename[0];
```

Comment: Only answer than correctly explains the type of `&filename`.

Comment: This doesn't explain ANYTHING. What is a char (*)[100] type?

Answer (score 4):

I like to be explicit about this and use

`file = &filename[0];`

`filename` is an identifier for an array. For the record, it is **not** a pointer (although it can *decay* to a pointer in certain instances). `filename[0]` is the zeroth element of this array. Taking the address of that gives you a pointer to the zeroth element of that array. Pointer arithmetic using `file` *is* valid since it points to a contiguous memory block that you own.

Answer (score 2):

Replace statement `file = &filename;` by `file = filename;`.

Answer (score 2):

```
file = filename;
```

or alternativly

```
file = &(filename[0]);
```

filename[100] is an array, and filename (without the brackets) points to that array;